# UIViewController and UIView Life cycles in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit, lifecycle

I am concerned to know the life cycles of a View Controller and and View. After Searching a lot on internet, I am still misunderstood with the following concepts:

- UIViewController controls the UIView or its root view via following callbacks:

  1. ViewDidLoad(_:)
  2. ViewWillAppear(_:)
  3. ViewDidAppear(_:)
  4. ViewWillDisappear(_:)
  5. ViewDidDisappear(_:)
- UIView controls the subview via following callbacks:

  1. didAddSubview(_:)
  2. willRemoveSubview(_:)
  3. willMove( toSuperView :)
  4. didMoveToSuperView(_:)

There are functions to control the life cycle of UIView in Controller, but  is there any function to control the life cycles of UIViewController.

In [this](https://medium.com/@amyjoscelyn/the-life-cycle-of-a-view-c98f296fd84e) article, Any mentioned that both have different life cycles and explained only for view's life cycles. Any help will be much appreciated...

Comment: what are you trying to do ? or you just asking in general how to use life cycle functions ?

Comment: Farhan, there is an enormous volume of information on the internet regarding the lifecycles of `UIView` and `UIViewController` and I encourage you to do more research and reading. There are also a number of questions and answers on Stack Overflow that directly relate to your question. I also encourage you to set up `print` statements in your Swift code to literally watch and learn how these lifecycle methods are executed... for example in your `override func viewWillAppear(_:)`, at the end of your code within this method, insert `print("\(#function) called")`.

Comment: @andrewbuilder are there more functions as I mentioned above. Any link to an informative article will be appreciated...

Comment: @Tobi I am just asking it for my understanding...

Comment: its pretty much big topic for an answer ! make it more specific we might be able to help

Comment: @Tobi I am concerned to know the life cycle callbacks of UIViewController and UIView...

Comment: callbacks are handled automatically in ViewControllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the life cycle of `UIViewController` and `UIView` is not directly related, and they can be treated independently.

For `UIViewController`, its life cycle is affected by how it is used:

1. If used as a `childViewController` in a container viewController (`UINavigationController`/`UITabBarController`/`UISplitViewController`, etc.), or as `window.rootViewController`, its lifecycle will be:

   ```
   init
   viewDidLoad
   willMoveToParentViewController:
   viewWillAppear:
   didMoveToParentViewController:
   viewDidAppear:
   willMoveToParentViewController:
   viewWillDisappear:
   didMoveToParentViewController:
   viewDidDisappear:
   dealloc
   ```
2. If you just use `viewController.view` to add it to the other views, its life cycle may only be:

   ```
   init
   viewDidLoad
   viewWillAppear:
   viewDidAppear:
   dealloc
   ```